# Internal Server Error while using heroku and bcryptjs

Tags: node.js, json, heroku, middleware, bcrypt

My friend and I are developing a frontend website where we need to encrypt some data before it goes to a database. We were advised to use bcryptjs and so we did

On the following code you can see our middleware:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); //módulo NPM
const config = require('./config.js'); //ficheiro de configuração

let checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
let token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization'];
if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    token = token.slice(7, token.length); //remove a palavra ‘Bearer ’
    }
    if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, config.jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
    return res.json({
    success: false,
    message: 'O token não é válido.'
    });
    } else {
    req.decoded = decoded;
    next();
    }
    });
    } else {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Token indisponível.'
            });
            }
            };
            module.exports = {
            checkToken: checkToken
            }
```

Router:

```
router.get('/list', middleware.checkToken,utilizadorController.list);
```

App.js:

```
app.use('/utilizador', middleware.checkToken,utilizadorRouters)
```

We think everything is connected correctly however when we run our site just appears a message saying "Internal Server Error", since we are using heroku we executed `heroku logs --tail` this command so we can have access to logs, we found out that the problem is on the terminal `2021-06-02T20:06:44.372296+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`, this is related to the first if at the middleware code (posted above)

Why are we getting this error? And does it have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line

```
let token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.headers['authorization'];
```

finds no token in either header.  So `token` comes back undefined, rather than a string. So `token.startsWith()` doesn't work and gives the error you saw.

When something like this gacks, the web server throws back a 500 error to the browser.

To troubleshoot: Do `console.log(req.headers)` and look at the output. It looks to me like the http request you send lacks either one of those headers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, we used that command to check it and u r absolutely right it says the error is 500, about those headers as i said we r new at this so could u kindly explain what exactly are the headers u r talking about and whats their purpose (sorry for our ignorance)